# postgres start issue after server patching (but my concern is if I am using correct data directory?)

Tags: bitbucket, postgresql-9.2

I usually get postgres issue after each server reboot(after monthly RHEL server patching).
We are using postgres for our Bitbucket code repository.

**OS:** RedHat

**Postgres version:** PostgreSQL 9.2.24

I everytime do below steps to fix the postgres after server reboot.

`**Error:**`

`sudo systemctl status postgresql.service`

`â postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server`
   ``` Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; ``vendor preset: disabled) ```
   `Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2018-04-14 01:46:27 EDT; 1 weeks 2 days ago`
  ``` Process: 1028 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} ``(code=exited, status=216/GROUP) ```

**Sol:**

`1. sudo systemctl stop postgresql.service`

`2. su postgres`

`3. initdb --locale en_GB.UTF-8 -E UTF8 -D '**/var/lib/postgres/data**'`

`4. sudo mkdir /var/run/postgresql/`

`5. sudo chmod 777 /var/run/postgresql/`

`6. sudo systemctl start postgresql.service`

**My Concern:**

I see two different directories on server.

`1. **/var/lib/pgsql/data/**`

`2. **/var/lib/postgres/data**`

and my DB shows below in use:

`postgres=# SHOW data_directory;`
`data_directory`

`---------------------`

`/var/lib/pgsql/data`

I believe the command I am running in step 3. is incorrect. I should use something else to start the DB using existing '/var/lib/pgsql/data' .
Can somebody please help me with the expert advise?